# VS Studio Git "The given path's format is not supported"

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I have a problem that since some time I can not pull from my git repo anymore in Visual Studio. Pushing works just fine. I am not an expert with git, but never had problems using it with vs studio before. Now I get the error shown in the picture but have no idea which path this is actually referring to.

Somebody had similar issues an can help?

[image]